Does there exist a harmonic map $F: (S,g_0)\to T^2 $ for which $F(\alpha_u(t))$ and $F(\beta_v(t))$ are all geodesics?
Let $S=[0,1]^2$. Ignoring issues having to do with boundaries and corners, a chart is a diffeomorphism $\varphi \colon S \to S$. Let $g_0$ denote the flat (euclidean) metric. Given a chart $\varphi \colon (S, g_0) \to (S, g_0)$, which need not be an isometry, consider the curves $\alpha_u(t)=\varphi^{-1}(u,t)$ and $\beta_v(t)=\varphi^{-1}(t,v)$ in $S$ which are assumed to not be geodesics.

Does there exist a harmonic map $F: (S,g_0)\to T^2 $ for which $F(\alpha_u(t))$ and $F(\beta_v(t))$ are all geodesics?

Here $T^2$ has the quotient metric of $\mathbb R^2\backslash \mathbb Z^2$.

What is $T^2$? Do you want the images to be parametrised geodesics or unparametrised geodesics?

@JanBohr $T^2$ is the torus. I want the images to be unparametrised geodesics

And which metric do you put on the torus? If it's just the quotient metric of $\mathbb R^2\backslash \mathbb Z^2$, then the quotient map, restricted to the square $[0,1]^2$ is a local isometry. Hence, it is harmonic and sends geodesic to (even parametrised) geodesics.

@JanBohr Yes I want the quotient metric. I was thinking of your example as well and I see that your example indeed shows existence of the desired harmonic map. I was more interested in the possible cases where the $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are not geodesics, but where $F$ sends them to geodesics on $T^2$. Let me make those changes to the question, thanks

This is not an answer, but a long comment. Let me propose a reformulation of (a version of) your question:
If $M$ is a manifold and $\nabla,\nabla'$ are two affine torsion free connections, then we say that $\nabla$ and $\nabla'$ are projectively equivalent, if they share the same unparametrised geodesics (i.e. every $\nabla'$-geodesic can be reparemetrised to a $\nabla$-geodesic). The equivalence class $\mathfrak{p}=[\nabla]$ is called projective structure and the set of all projective structures is denoted $\mathfrak{P}(M)$. It contains as (proper) subset the projective structures that can be represented by a Levi-Civita connection:
$$
\mathfrak{P}_{LC}(M)=\{[\nabla^g]:g \text{ Riemannian metric}\}
$$
Given a local diffeomorphism $F\colon M\to N$ between manifolds, pulling back connections induces an isomorphism $F^*\colon \mathfrak{P}(N)\to \mathfrak{P}(M).$
Suppose now that $(M,g)$ and $(N,h)$ are Riemannian, then we have the following subset of $\mathfrak{P}_{LC}(M)$
$$
\mathfrak{P}_H(M) = \{F^*[\nabla^h]: F\colon (M,g)\to(N,h) \text{ harmonic local diffeo}\} \subset \mathfrak{P}_{LC}(M)
$$
and one can ask how this subset can be characterised.
In your question, let's ignore the boundary and put $M=(0,1)^2$ (with $g$=Euclidean), then $\mathfrak{p}_0:=\varphi^*[\nabla^{g_0}]=[\nabla^{\varphi^* g_0}] \in \mathfrak{P}_{LC}(M)$ is a particular element of the set on the right hand side. Putting $N=\mathbb T^2$ (with Euclidean metric), you're essentially asking whether $\mathfrak{p_0}\in \mathfrak{P}_H(M)$. (In contrast to your question I'm demanding $F$ to be a local diffeo.)
